# Fixing Indexing when Appending Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am appending three CSVs:

```
df = pd.read_csv("places_1.csv")
temp = pd.read_csv("places_2.csv")
df = df.append(temp)
temp = pd.read_csv("places_3.csv")
df = df.append(temp)
print(df.head(20))
```

the joined table looks like:

```
  location  device_count  population
0        A            11         NaN
1        B            12         NaN
2        C            13         NaN
3        D            14         NaN
4        E            15         NaN
0        F            21         NaN
1        G            22         NaN
2        H            23         NaN
3        I            24         NaN
4        J            25         NaN
0        K            31         NaN
1        L            32         NaN
2        M            33         NaN
3        N            34         NaN
4        O            35         NaN
```

As you can see the indices are not unique.

When I call this iloc function to multiply the population column by 2:

```
df2 = df.copy
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.iloc[index, df.columns.get_loc('population')] = row['device_count'] * 2
```

I get the following erronious result:

```
  location  device_count  population
0        A            11        62.0
1        B            12        64.0
2        C            13        66.0
3        D            14        68.0
4        E            15        70.0
0        F            21         NaN
1        G            22         NaN
2        H            23         NaN
3        I            24         NaN
4        J            25         NaN
0        K            31         NaN
1        L            32         NaN
2        M            33         NaN
3        N            34         NaN
4        O            35         NaN
```

For each CSV it is overwriting the indexes of the first CSV
I have also tried creating a new column of integers and calling df.set_index(). That did not work.

Any tips?

Comment: add ignore_index, ``df.append(temp,  ignore_index=True)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, use `ignore_index`, second, don't use `append`, use `pd.concat([temp1, temp2, temp3], ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: Why use concat instead of append?  @Igor Riven

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, you can use `ignore_index`, and you probably should use `pd.concat` here. Alternatively, for other situations where you are not combining DataFrames, you can also use `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` to change the indices after the fact.

Additionally, you should avoid using `iterrows()` for reasons listed in the docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#iteration). Using the following works way better:

```
df.loc[:, 'population'] = df.loc[:, 'device_count'].astype('int') * 2
```

Comment: the *2 is just a proxy for a more complex function I am running that involves multiple columns from the row.

Comment: why use concat instead of append?

Comment: @SteveScott It's more flexible, and in much wider use, so is likely to be more efficient. https://machinelearningknowledge.ai/tutorial-pandas-concat-pandas-append-pandas-merge-pandas-join/

Comment: Strange. `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` or `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` should work...

Comment: If vectorization is not an option for your function, I recommend you refer to cs95's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/55557758?noredirect=1) for a performance analysis of modifying dataframes with functions. You'll notice `iterrows()` is the last tool you should reach for